# Возможно ли в телеграм-боте заносить в БД регистрационные данные?

Tags: telegram-bot

Один знакомый хочет, чтобы юзеры телеграм-бота давили на кнопку,
и в результате регистрационными данными заполнялась собственная база данных;

я отвечаю - что данными заполнять базу конечно можно, но это будут черт-те какие любые данные, никак на самом деле с юзером не связанные - что он введет, то и попадет в базу, и никакая валидация тут не решит проблему, т.к. вся подлинная регистрационная информация хранится у телеграма, и он ее не отдаст.

Но он настаивает на своей правоте. Кто прав?

Comment: У телеграма можно узнать ник (если есть), отображаемое имя и телефон через "фичу" получения номера собеседника при расшаривании контактных данных и то если юзер нажмет на кнопку.

Comment: ну а дальше то что? это же в любом случае будет просто собранная информация, которую никак иначе кроме как информацию вообще не используешь? логиниться же все равно будут по данным которые хранятся в телеграме?

Comment: Знакомому виднее что дальше. Я без понятия зачем информацию через телеграм собирать. Я только знаю какую достоверную информацию можно достать и как. Остальное все - фантазии собеседника.